# Adaptor Pattern

Tags: c++, design-patterns

What are the practical uses of Adaptor Pattern?

Comment: Do you have a specific scenario where you consider using it? If so describe it! Otherwise, use Google or read a book.

Answer (score 2):

The STL stack is a real-life adapter.

Other adapters in the STL are:

- queues
- priority queues
- reverse iterators
- insert iterators
- stream iterators

see also [design patterns used in STL(standard template library)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2698474/design-patterns-used-in-stlstandard-template-library/)

Answer (score 1):

Lets say you have two payment gateways and you want a general API for both. 
You could use the adaptor pattern to "Adapt" the payment APIs into your own.

This way your application has one standard API for dealing with payment gateways.

Answer (score 0):

For example to adapt an old API to a new API so legacy code can use the new API through the adaptor.